# Inequality with Gamma function

Tags: calculus, inequality, gamma-function

I need to solve the  following inequality 
$$\Gamma(a_1)\Gamma(a_2)>\Gamma(a_1+a_2+x)$$
is true.

Of course  $a_1,a_2,x$ are positive real numbers. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: The inequality does not make sense if you do not put any constraints on $b$. E.g. Let $a_1=a_2=1$ and $b=100$. I think you should invert the inequality sign.

Comment: The equality $\Gamma(a+1)=a\cdot\Gamma(a)$ may be useful here.